# Simple log in unity c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging

It should be simple, but still can't find a straight answer:

How can I log a simple message using C# Unity script?

I tried this:

```
Debug.Log("Hello Log");
```

It doesn't work or I'm not looking at the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Debug.Log("Hello Log");` can be found on the **Console Tab**.

[image]

---

For you to be able to see it:

**1**.You must put it in a function from a script.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello Log");
    }
}
```

**2**.Script must be attached to a GameObject.

[image]

**3**.Both the script and the GameObject it is attached to must be enabled.

[image]

**4**.Reset the Layout if you can't see the **Console tab**.

[image]

**EDIT:**

> I tested it on Android Device. That's why I didn't see it.

In that case, use Android Monitor from Android Studio to view the log from your Android device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I tested it on Android Device. Thats why I didn't see it.

Comment: @David Oh I see. Check my Edit for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Simple : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Attach this script to component and simple message will be there  when you start project");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: unity documentation link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html