# Input.GetKeyDown() not working in Unity5.5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the below code which I cant make it work, I have created an empty game object and created and attached this script to it. The script shows no compiler 
errors but when I execute the code, and I press the corresponding key, nothing happens.I am using Unity5.5

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelloWorld : MonoBehaviour {
// 

Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        float location = 5.0f;
        float homeLocation = 2.1f;
        //float distance = location - homeLocation;
        print ("Welcome to GoHome !");
        print ("A game where you need to find your way back");
        print ("Location:" + location);
        if (location > homeLocation) {
            print ("Go back to get home");
        }
        if (location < homeLocation) {
            print ("go forward to get home");
        }
        if (location == homeLocation) {
            print ("you are at home");
        }   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftBracket))
            print ("left bracket key pressed");
    }

}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831304/simple-log-in-unity-c-sharp-script/43831339#43831339) for why Debug.Log is not showing when key is pressed.

Comment: try other keys too

Comment: I have tried other keys its not working either, Debug.Log  works if I put it in else statement, this means my if is not working.Is this problem with unity editor as I have 5.5?

Comment: Just a note: I've tried your code with Unity5.5 and it worked for me: left bracket key pressed
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
HelloWorld:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/HelloWorld.cs:35)

Comment: Did you see the print statement? That's strange, why am I not seeing the print statement.

Comment: Make sure the game window has focus by clicking on it after pressing the play button.

Comment: @Leo,This worked,Thanks a lot.I did not know this.I am still learning .